# MVC 5 Razor Variable Change on HTML Button click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

NET and MVC, I'm trying to work on a beginner project and I'm kinda of stuck.

I have data model that contains multiple picture paths in it and I'm wondering how could I change which the picture I want to display in my view on button click. Example: show picture 1, click a HTML button, and change to show picture 2.

This is what I got so far? How am I supposed to change the picID variable? Could someone explain please?

```
    <tr>
       <td><button type="button">Click this to change the picID variable</button></td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Picture.ElementAt(picID).picturePath)</td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

What you'll want to do is have the button invoke an action method that changes picID and returns your view. Something like /controller/changepic/1. Changepic will update picID to 2 and then return the same view and model.

The tricky part here is that button is generally used to submit forms. So you either have to add an event handler to manually set the action link or use an anchor element (@Html.ActionLink) styled like a button. You can use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) to do that kind of styling.

I made a lot of assumptions, but hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways. Check this out:

```
<img id="theImage" src="" />
<ul>
    @foreach (var i in Model.Picture)
    { 
        <li><a href="#" data-image="@i.picturePath" class="change-image">@i.picturePath</a></li>
    }
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //Click event for the image links
        $('.change-image').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            $('#theImage').attr('src', $(this).data('image'));
        });

        //Display the first link
        $('#theImage').attr('src', $('ul li:first-child a.change-image').data('image'));
    });
</script>
```

Notice that I'm using jQuery.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: I think we are think on different terms. The model.Picture is a list/array of multiple pictures. So saying model.Picture.ElementAt(0).picturePath will get me the first picture in the array. I'm just not sure how to change that picID value in raazor or javascript to where I can still pull back from my model.

Int my example code above I am just keeping it simple and showing the plain text path for now.

Comment: @CatfishAlpha45 In order to be able to change the current image on the view, you must either get all your images paths (your array) to a JS object or to the HTML structure. In my example, I'm creating a link for each path, and changing the presented image when the corresponding link is clicked. Have you give a try to my code?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation, I wanted to change an image depending on the combo value, so I use JQuery

in the cshtml I put a  that contains the images I have:

```
<img class="imgf"> ...
<img class="imgp"> ...
<img class="imgb"> ...
```

The Jquery code on Combo Change:

```
var model = $("#ComboValue").val();
var pathgimgf = "/Images/" + model + "/imgf.png";
var pathimga = "/Images/" + model + "/imga.png";
var pathimgb = "/Images/" + model + "/imgb.png";


$(".imgf").attr("src", pathgimgf);
$(".imgp").attr("src", pathimga);
$(".imgb").attr("src", pathimgb);
```

I hope this can help you.